# error: request for memver '' in '', which is of non-class type 'int*'//Use a method inside void function to print info from a struct

Tags: c++, class, methods, struct

So, im doing a programm in which i use classes and structs to store info about a product, which the user will introduce, and i have a void function to print the info (bar code, name, weight, **date**,price and available in stock)

**The question is, how to correctly call the method inside the function to use the info from the struct?**

This is the function i use to print the info from the struct, the parameters are the struct and a pointer for the date bc the function to store the info already returns the struct.

```
void imprimirDatos(struct Producto prod, int* pA){
    cout<<"\nCodigo de barras: "<<prod.codbarr<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<prod.nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Peso: "<<prod.peso<<endl;
    cout<<"Fecha: "<<*pA.mostrar()<<endl;
    >(^^this is the date^^)
    cout<<"Precio mayoreo: "<<prod.PM<<endl;
    cout<<"Precio menudeo: "<<prod.pm<<endl;
    cout<<"Existencia: "<<prod.existencia<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------\n";
}
```

but when i try to print the date it shows me the error mentioned, i assume its bc its not the right way to call the method.

this is the part where i store the info in the struct:

```
cout<<"Dame la fecha de hoy (formato aammdd/yyyymmdd): \n";
cin>>prod.fecha;
*pA=prod.fecha;
```

The constructor:

```
Fecha::Fecha(long fecha){//so the user inputs the date in format: yyyymmdd-> 20200923
    ano=int(fecha/10000);
    mes=int((fecha-ano*10000)/100);
    dia=int(fecha-ano*10000-mes*100);
}
```

The method/function of the class:

```
void Fecha::mostrar(){
    cout<<dia<<"/"<<mes<<"/"<<ano<<endl;
}
```

This is the order i have the code (excluding the main):

```
struct Producto{

    string codbarr;
    string nombre;
    float peso;
    int fecha;
    float PM;
    float pm;
    int existencia;

};

class Fecha{

private:
    int dia, mes, ano;
public:
    Fecha(int,int,int);
    Fecha(long);
    void mostrar();
};

Fecha::Fecha(long fecha){//En caso  de que se ingrese 1 solo número empezando por el año, e.g. 20200923
    ano=int(fecha/10000);
    mes=int((fecha-ano*10000)/100);
    dia=int(fecha-ano*10000-mes*100);
}

struct Producto llenarInfo(struct Producto prod, int* pA){

        cout<<"Dame la fecha de hoy (formato aammdd): \n";
        cin>>prod.fecha;
        *pA=prod.fecha;
        fflush(stdin);

    return prod;
}

void Fecha::mostrar(){
    cout<<dia<<"/"<<mes<<"/"<<ano<<endl;
}

void imprimirDatos(struct Producto prod, int* pA){
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<prod.nombre<<endl;
    //cout<<"Fecha: "<<*pA.mostrar()<<endl;
    cout<<"Fecha: "<<prod.fecha.mostrar()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `*pA.mostrar()` is wrong because `pA`, which is `int*`, don't have members.

Comment: You may want `prod.fecha.mostrar()` instead.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To use the info from the struct, use the info from the struct instead of using `pA`, which is outside the struct.

Comment: Or maybe `Fecha(prod.fecha).mostrar()` instead of `prod.fecha.mostrar()`?

Comment: thanks for the reply @MikeCAT, alredy tried both `prod.fecha.mostrar()` and `Fecha(prod.fecha).mostrar() `, the 1st gave me "request for member: 'mostrar' in 'prod.Producto::fecha' which is of non-class type 'int'" error and the 2nd, a lot more

Comment: `cout<<"Fecha: ";Fecha(prod.fecha).mostrar();cout<<endl;` should work for printing.

Comment: And yes, i can use the info directly from the struct, in fact, use 3 different variables for month, day and year, but in this case its a must to use the class (i think thats what you meant) `prod.year, prod.month, prod.day`

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank You SO much, `cout<<"Fecha: ";Fecha(prod.fecha).mostrar();cout<<endl;` did work, now i can continue to burn my eyelashes studying, thumbs up for you!